# Howto integrate Jasper HTML Report in Spring View (Conceptional)

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, conceptual

Howto integrate Jasper HTML Report in Spring View (Conceptional)

I would like to create a kind of dashboard in my Spring framework Application.
I have a view (jsp) and would like to include Jasper Report HTML/Pie Chart Image Output ( in my html sample) in a specific part of my produced HTML Page.

Is this possible to do ? If yes. Will the report be generated in the controller and sent to the view by ModelView ?

My View (dashboard.jsp) looks like this (sample):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Key Figures</h2>
<table border=1 width=700>
<tbody> 
    <tr> <Navigation Items like Buttons and Tabs> </tr>
    <tr height=200>
        <td><c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
                <li>${listValue}</li>
            </c:forEach>
                </td>
        <td>Other Content from the Model</td>

    </tr>
    <tr height=200>
        <td><My Pie Chart 1></td>
        <td><My Pie Chart 2></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mcfly soft: have you able to find any solution for above issue. If so can you please share it.